# Using lodash debounce to set the state in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, debouncing

I know this has been asked a thousand times, but I am not sure how I am doing this wrong. I have read tons of stackoverflow and what I am looking for is: **How am I doing this wrong?**

So consider the following function:

```
setFormValues(fieldName, value) {
    let values = this.state.values;

    values[fieldName] = value;

    this.setState({
      values: values
    }, () => {
      debounce(() => {
        this.setState({
          validationErrors: validator(this.state.validations, this.state.values),
        });
      }, 350);
    });
  }
```

Every time an element value changes, we pass that to the form (each element is its own react class that calls this function). After we set the value in the form (used for posting data) we have to validate the values of the form.

Lets look at the validator file:

```
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import startCase from 'lodash.startcase';

/**
 * Validate the form values.
 */
export const validator = (validations, formValues) => {
  let validationMessages = {};

  for (const key in formValues) {
    if (validations.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      const fieldValidations  = validations[key];
      const validationMessage = createValidationMessage(key, formValues[key], formValues, fieldValidations);

      if (validationMessage !== null) {
        validationMessages[key] = validationMessage;
      }
    }
  }

  return validationMessages;
}

/**
 * Create a a validation message when the validatiom for the form value
 * fails against the form field validations.
 */
const createValidationMessage = (fieldName, value, formValues, fieldValidations) => {
  let message = null;

  fieldValidations.forEach((fieldValidation) => {
    if (fieldValidation.hasOwnProperty('cannot_percede_field')) {
      if (formValues.hasOwnProperty(fieldValidation.cannot_percede_field)) {
        const formValue = formValues[fieldValidation.cannot_percede_field];

        if (isFutureDate(value, fieldValidation)) {
          message = {
            message: 'Date cannot be greator then today.',
            isError: fieldValidation.show_error,
          };
        }

        if (isDateLessThen(value, formValue, fieldValidation)) {
          message = {
            message: 'Date cannot be less then: ' + startCase(fieldValidation.cannot_percede_field) + '.',
            isError: fieldValidation.show_error,
          };
        }
      }
    }
  })

  return message;
}

/**
 * Is the date in question greator then date saved?
 */
const isFutureDate = (value, validationObject) => {
  if (validationObject.cannot_be_future_date) {
    return moment(value).isAfter(moment());
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Is the date in question less then the date saved?
 */
const isDateLessThen = (value, formValue, validationObject) => {
  if (validationObject.cannot_percede_field) {
    return moment(value).isBefore(formValue);
  }

  return false;
}
```

All we do is loop over the values, check if the validator has specific rules for that field. In this case if the field sates it cannot precede another field, we state the validation message, if the field in question is greater then today, again we set the message.

**Whats the issue?**

If I take off the debounce, and leave it as setting the sate with validation messages, assuming there are any, the form input is very slow. But the validation works and the messages are displayed properly.

if I leave the debounce as it is, and force a failure (for example a date field that precedes another date field) nothing happens.

What I understand is that the issue might be I am calling debounce over and over again and thus the function never fires. but when you select a date, it should only call it once, wait 350 ms and then either show or not the validation errors.

**What am I doing wrong with lodashes debounce such that it doesn't even work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reason for "form input is slow" is you mutate `state` which is no-no for React. Once you mutate state component is not re-rendered. It's updated only when debounced validator calls `setState`.

While I agree with Ori Drori you may reshape your logic to run validation in  different way you definitely need to stop mutating state like

```
setFormValues(fieldName, value) {
    let values = this.state.values;
    // here you mutate this.state.values[fieldName]!
    values[fieldName] = value;

    this.setState({
      values: values
    }
```

and do

```
setFormValues(fieldName, value) {
    this.setState(({values: oldValues}) => ({
      values: {
        ...oldValues,
        [fieldName]: value
      }
    }), ........
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

Debounce takes a function, and returns a new function that wraps the original one. Whenever the wrapper function is invoked, it waits the defined time before invoking the wrapped function. If the wrapper is called again, it postpones the calling of the wrapped function by the allotted time, and so on. Debounce works by maintaining an internal timer. Whenever the wrapper is called, the timer resets, and only when the defined time passed without a reset, the wrapped function is called.

When you use debounce, you need to define the function once, and call it many times. If you keep creating a new function (like you need inside the setState), the internal timer of the function never resets, because you never call the function more than once. In effect, you get a single delay, and then the wrapped function is called, etc...

I would generate a `validate` debounced function, and call it in the `setState`'s callback:

```
validate = debounce(() => {
  this.setState(({ validations, values }) => ({
    validationErrors: validator(this.state.validations, this.state.values),
  }))
})

setFormValues(fieldName, value) {
  let values = this.state.values;

  values[fieldName] = value;

  this.setState({
      values: values
    }, this.validate;
  });
}
```

**Why are your validations so slow?**

While I agree with @skyboyer that you shouldn't mutate the state, it's probably not the reason for the validation being slow. Looking at the validation, it's clear that for every keystroke, the script runs all validations relevant to all form inputs. Two of this validations use moment.js to convert and compare dates, which is very slow.

Since you know the current value when you run `setFormValues(fieldName, value)`, only validate that field. In addition, convert the `formValues[fieldValidation.cannot_percede_field]` and the future data via moment once, and cache the result for use, instead of converting on each key stroke, or ditch moment and use native js, or a faster library.